# Finding average of multiple rows in a file

Tags: text-processing, awk

**Input File:**

```
1 2 3 4 5 

6 4 2 1 2

3 6 7 8 9
```

and so on..

**Desired Output:**

```
3

3

6.6
```

I have many files and each file with different numbers of column but the no. of rows is the same 25000. I want to have the same number of rows but only one column.

Any suggestion by using `awk`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this:

```
awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) t+=$i; print (t/(i-1)); t=0}' filename
```